# $\Delta$-complex structure on $S^2$ with three 2-simplices

Tags: algebraic-topology

Does there exist a $\Delta$-complex structure on $S^2$ which has exactly three $2$-simplices? It's easy to think of examples with two or four $2$-simplices as well as a CW complex structure with exactly three 2-cells. However, I cannot think of a $\Delta$-complex structure for $S^2$ with exactly three $2$-simplices and I'm not sure how I would go about proving that one does not exist. Every structure I can think of with three $2$-simplices has at least one hole making it homeomorphic to a disk or something else instead of $S^2$. Perhaps there is a way to use the Euler characteristic of $S^2$ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of edges of three disjoint 2-simplices is equal to $3 \cdot 3 = 9$. In order to form a $\Delta$-complex structure of $S^2$, those $9$ edges must be glued in pairs, so $9$ must be an even number, which it isn't.

In general, the number of 2-simplices in any $\Delta$-complex structure on any compact surface (with empty boundary) is even.